# ggplot2 timeseries chart with background shading

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I have an excel graph that I want to create in R.

[image: Excel Chart]

I tried recreating it with some dummy data

```
a<-rnorm(12)
a_ts<-ts(a, start=c(2015, 1), frequency=12)
a_time<-time(a_ts)
a_series<-ts.union(ret=a_ts, date=a_time)
a_series_df<-as.data.frame(a_series)

ggplot() +
geom_rect(data=data.frame(xmin=decimal_date(as.Date(c("2015-01-01"))),
xmax=decimal_date(as.Date(c("2015-05-31"))), ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax), fill="pink", alpha=0.5) +
geom_line(data = a_series_df, aes(x=date,y=ret, color='blue')) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) 
#this does not work
#scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 month",   labels=date_format("%B-%d")) +
#scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

which looks like this

[image: R version]

I am struggling with the date conversions and also setting the x and y origins to zero and getting the axis labels right, the last two lines of code work for non-date data points. I would also like to have a legend below the chart for series1, series2 and and entry for the shaded area.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update after applying the suggestions:

[image: X axis should be at y = 0 everything else should stay as it is, as in the excel]

Comment: How are the two separate lines distinguished in the data used in Excel ?  Can you provide a small example of the data used in original plot using `dput`.  Dummy data is fine but you need to add a column (e.g. a factor) that distinguishes the data in the separate lines.

Comment: I intentionally just printed one data series, I want to cut out excel completely. You can assume that I have a data frame/ xts object with 1 to n columns of data. For now I am happy to get a similar formatting as the excel graph for the dummy data.

Comment: If you run your code above, you will see that it generates an errors. Please make sure the sample code in your question works before posting. Cheers.

Comment: code fixed, as mentioned in the code the last two lines do not work in the time stamp version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example that should get you most of the way there.  This uses the `lubridate` package for working with date and times (Dates in this case).  This shows you one way you could plot two separate lines on the same plot with most of the requested modifications.  In this example an `alpha` of `0.05` is used.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

### Set up dummy data.
dayVec     <- seq(ymd('2016-01-01'), ymd('2016-01-10'), by = '1 day')
set.seed(1234)
dayCount   <- length(dayVec)
dayValVec1 <- rnorm(dayCount)
dayValVec2 <- rnorm(dayCount)
dayDF      <- data.frame(Date = rep(dayVec, 2),
                         DataType = factor(c(rep('A', dayCount), rep('B', dayCount))),
              Value = c(dayValVec1, dayValVec2))

### Dummy data in data frame (DataType is a factor)
dayDF
##          Date DataType       Value
## 1  2016-01-01        A -1.20706575
## 2  2016-01-02        A  0.27742924
## 3  2016-01-03        A  1.08444118
## 4  2016-01-04        A -2.34569770
## 5  2016-01-05        A  0.42912469
## 6  2016-01-06        A  0.50605589
## 7  2016-01-07        A -0.57473996
## 8  2016-01-08        A -0.54663186
## 9  2016-01-09        A -0.56445200
## 10 2016-01-10        A -0.89003783
## 11 2016-01-01        B -0.47719270
## 12 2016-01-02        B -0.99838644
## 13 2016-01-03        B -0.77625389
## 14 2016-01-04        B  0.06445882
## 15 2016-01-05        B  0.95949406
## 16 2016-01-06        B -0.11028549
## 17 2016-01-07        B -0.51100951
## 18 2016-01-08        B -0.91119542
## 19 2016-01-09        B -0.83717168
## 20 2016-01-10        B  2.41583518

ggplot(dayDF, aes(Date, Value, colour = DataType)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=ymd('2016-01-02'),
                  xmax = ymd('2016-01-06'),
                  ymin = -Inf,
                  ymax = Inf), fill = 'pink', alpha = 0.05) +
    scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format('%b-%d'), breaks = date_breaks('1 day'), expand=c(0,0)) +
    theme(axis.text.x     = element_text(angle=90),
          legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Note, the `date_breaks` value can be changed to `1 month` if you want to plot by month.  This example is just per day.

Comment: I will accept your answer if you please also add how to set the x axis to start at '2016-01-01' without that little offset

Comment: I updated the plotting command to specify `date_breaks`.  I will update the plot shortly.

Comment: @Markus.london The image has been updated to reflect the code change.

Comment: can you shift the starting points of the two lines to the left as in my original excel graph ? so that they start directly on the y-axis?

Comment: @Markus.london I have updated the code and plot, this should better reflect what you are asking for.

Comment: do you by any chance also know who to force the x and y axis to intersect at y = 0 , and still keep the date labels at the bottom, as in the excel version ?

Comment: What are you calling zero for the x-axis ?

Comment: I added a new picture of what I have now. I need the x axis from y = -240 to y = 0 everything else is perfect. The x axis labels should stay where they are, as in the excel version

Comment: For the "scale_x_" and "scale_y_" functions see the "limits" parameter. That should do it.

Comment: can you see anything in the code that sets the axis to where it is now ? I started a new question for it with an updated pic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676878/ggplot2-x-y-axis-intersect-while-keeping-axis-labels?noredirect=1#comment60944664_36676878 sth must be overwriting the limits it won't change it

Comment: I assume you have the answer you need in the other post.

Answer (score 3):

```
#Make data
a_time <- time(ts(rnorm(12), start=c(2015, 1), frequency=12))
a_series <-ts.union(ret=a_ts, date=a_time)
a_series_df <-as.data.frame(a_series)
a_series_df$date <- as.Date(format(date_decimal(a_series_df$date), 
                                   "%d-%m-%Y"), format="%d-%m-%Y")

dat_rect <- data.frame(
                    xmin = as.Date(c("2015-01-01")),
                    xmax = as.Date(c("2015-05-31")),
                    ymin = -Inf,
                    ymax = Inf
)

#Next time, if using functions not in base R, indicate what packages they are from
#decimal_date for example is from lubridate, which in this solution it is not needed.
ggplot() +
        geom_rect(data=dat_rect,
                  aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),
                  fill="pink", alpha=0.5) +
        geom_line(data=a_series_df, aes(x=date,y=ret, color='blue')) +

        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) +

#Set date
scale_x_date(date_breaks='1 month',
             date_minor_breaks='1 month',
             labels=date_format("%B-%d"),
             expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: annotate is preferred to geom_rect. geom_rect will draw a rectangle for every row in the data. This can affect how alpha works. See https://community.rstudio.com/t/geom-rect-ignores-the-alpha-argument/35322/5

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the values are actual `Date` objects:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(1492)
a <- rnorm(12)

a_ts <- ts(a, start=c(2015, 1), frequency=12)
a_time <- time(a_ts)

a_series <- ts.union(ret=a_ts, date=a_time)
a_series_df <- as.data.frame(a_series)
a_series_df$date <- as.Date(as.character(a_series_df$date), "%Y.%j")

rect_df <- data.frame(xmin=as.Date(c("2015-01-01")),
                      xmax=as.Date(c("2015-05-31")))

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data=rect_df,
            aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), 
            fill="pink", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(data = a_series_df, aes(x=date, y=ret), color='blue') +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), labels=date_format("%b-%d"), 
               date_breaks="1 month") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), labels=percent) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

[image]