# ggplot2 x - y axis intersect while keeping axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, axis-labels

I posted my original question yesterday which got solved perfectly here

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668078/ggplot2-timeseries-chart-with-background-shading)

I made a few addition to my code

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

### Set up dummy data.
dayVec     <- seq(ymd('2016-01-01'), ymd('2016-01-10'), by = '1 day')
dayCount   <- length(dayVec)
dayValVec1 <- c(0,-0.22,0.15,0.3,0.4,0.10,0.17,0.22,0.50,0.89)
dayValVec2 <- c(0,0.2,-0.17,0.6,0.16,0.41,0.55,0.80,0.90,1.00)
dayValVec3 <- dayValVec2
dayDF      <- data.frame(Date = rep(dayVec, 3),
                     DataType = factor(c(rep('A', dayCount), rep('B',   dayCount), rep('C', dayCount))),
                     Value = c(dayValVec1, dayValVec2, dayValVec3))


ggplot(dayDF, aes(Date, Value, colour = DataType)) +
theme_bw() +
ggtitle("Cumulative Returns \n") +
scale_color_manual("",values = c("#033563", "#E1E2D2", "#4C633C"),
                    labels = c("Portfolio ", "Index ", "In-Sample ")) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = ymd('2016-01-01'),
            xmax = ymd('2016-01-06'),
            ymin = -Inf,
            ymax = Inf
            ), fill = "#E1E2D2", alpha = 0.03, colour = "#E1E2D2") +
geom_line(size = 2) +
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format('%b-%d'), 
               breaks = date_breaks('1 day'),
               expand = c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous( expand = c(0,0), labels = percent) +
theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle = 90), 
    axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line  = element_line(size = 1),
    axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1),
    axis.text  = element_text(size = 20, colour = "#033563"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 2),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 40, face = "bold", colour = "#033563"),
    legend.position = 'bottom',
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#033563", size = 20),
    legend.key  = element_blank()
    )
```

which produces this output

[image: Graph]

The only thing that I still cannot get working is the position of the x axis. I want the x axis to be at y = 0 but still keep the x axis labels under the chart, exactly as in the excel version of it. I know the data sets are not the same but I didn't have the original data at hand so I produced some dummy data. Hope this was worth a new question, thanks.

```
> grid.ls(grid.force())
GRID.gTableParent.12660
background.1-5-7-1
spacer.4-3-4-3
panel.3-4-3-4
grill.gTree.12619
  panel.background.rect.12613
  panel.grid.minor.y.zeroGrob.12614
  panel.grid.minor.x.zeroGrob.12615
  panel.grid.major.y.polyline.12617
  panel.grid.major.x.zeroGrob.12618
geom_rect.rect.12607
GRID.polyline.12608
panel.border.rect.12610
axis-l.3-3-3-3
axis.line.y.polyline.12631
axis
axis-b.4-4-4-4
axis.line.x.polyline.12624
axis
xlab.5-4-5-4
ylab.3-2-3-2
guide-box.6-4-6-4
title.2-4-2-4
> grid.gget("axis.1-1-1-1", grep=T)
NULL
```

Comment: _"Also is there a way to show the gridlines on top of the geom_rect"_ - they are on top of the plot here (ggplot2 2.1.0).

Comment: Ah ok just too thin to see them properly

Comment: Is using a `geom_hline(intercept=0)` an option?

Comment: I would prefer having the ticks as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` doesn't make this easy. Below is one-way to approach this interactively. Basically, you just grab the relevant part of the plot (the axis line and ticks) and reposition them.

If `p` is your plot

```
p
grid.force()
# grab the relevant parts - have a look at grid.ls()
tck <- grid.gget("axis.1-1-1-1", grep=T)[[2]] # tick marks
ax <- grid.gget("axis.line.x", grep=T)        # x-axis line

# add them to the plot, this time suppressing the x-axis at its default position
p + lapply(list(ax, tck), annotation_custom, ymax=0) + 
          theme(axis.line.x=element_blank(), 
                axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Which produces

[image]

A quick note: the more recent versions of `ggplot2` have the design decision to not show the axis. Also changes to `axis.line` are not automatically passed down to the `x` and `y` axis. Therefore, I tweaked your theme to define     `axis.line.x` and `axis.line.y` separately.

That siad, perhaps its easier (and more robust??) to use `geom_hline` as suggested in the comments, and `geom_segment` for the ticks.

Comment: Thanks this looks really good, I get an error in the lapply line Error: no applicable method for 'validGrob' applied to an object of class "NULL" do I need any additional libs ?

Comment: Did you check that tck and ax have correct object (rather than null)  - seems like they have not been grabbed (btw what R version and ggplot2 version are you using?)

Comment: tck and ax ar NULL, would you mind posting a working version ? R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06), ggplot2_1.0.1

Comment: This may not be the issue - but your R version is quite dated - im at v3.2.4: are you able to upgrade? Also im using ggplot2 v2.1.0. But regradless, try: If your plot is being displayed, type `grid.ls(grid.force())` to get a list of the grobs. Do you see the names of the grobs that I used in the `get` calls?

Comment: I see these ones 
axis-l.3-3-3-3
    axis.line.y.polyline.12407
    axis
  axis-b.4-4-4-4
    axis.line.x.polyline.12400
    axis

Comment: okay, so you can see the grobs: starting at  `axis-b.4-4-4-4`, these come after it `axis.line.x..polyline.226` (your number may be different), `axis`, `axis.1-1-1-1` and `axis.2-1-2-1`. Do you see these additional terms?  Also as you can see the polyline grob, what does `grid.gget("axis.line.x", grep=T)` return?

Comment: I addded the returns under my original post

Comment: Thank you - yep, the grid.ls returns more items for me, so it appears as if it is a version issue (ggplot2 had a recent extensive rewrite and grabbing grobs like this is often not robust to such changes). Can you upgrade?

Comment: I am on a mac atm, it doesn't look like there are updates available. I will try on windows tmrw

Comment: okay. - give me a bump tomorrow if you are stll having difficulties. Not a mac user, but id think there would be a more recent R version (unless your mac OS is  bit older as well )

Comment: Ok got it,it works, updated R, one last question how does your 
scale_x_datetime(expand = c(0,0), labels = date_format('%b-%d'), breaks = date_breaks('1 day')) 
line look like ? I get Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only

Comment: Great stuff. I got no warnings from your code (other then i needed the scales library). Your x-axis is class POSIXct (`str(dayDF)`) so i dont understand the error. I assume you just reinstalled all packages  since you just upgraded?

Comment: I have to figure out which package I am missing now . I am importing library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)

Comment: Yes, they are the four packages I used.

Comment: It's not a design decision - it's a bug

Comment: problem was scale_x_datetime should be scale_x_date