# How can I add tick marks at y=0 when y-axis goes negative in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add tick marks at `y=0` when `y=0` isn't at the bottom of the y-axis? In this crude example, the y-axis ranges from -$20,000 to $20,000, I added a `geom_hline` at `y=0`, and removed the axis ticks. However, I can't figure out how to add subtle ticks on the line at `y=0` which is in the middle of the chart:

```
diamonds %>%
  mutate(price = ifelse(cut == "Very Good", price * -1, price)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "points"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black")) +
  labs(title = "Diamonds")
```

There's an obnoxious number of questions about removing tick marks and spacing tick marks *along* the x- and y- axes, but I could not find an answer to my question. Thank you!

Comment: not sure id this is still applicable but ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676878/ggplot2-x-y-axis-intersect-while-keeping-axis-labels

Comment: You could add something like this: `geom_segment(data=data.frame(), aes(y=rep(-700,6), yend=rep(700,6), x=0:5, xend=0:5)) +`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this with `annotate` or equivalently with `geom='segment'`

```
x.axis.labels <- seq(0,5,0.25) # positions of the subtle ticks
diamonds %>%
  mutate(price = ifelse(cut == "Very Good", price * -1, price)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "points"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black")) +
  labs(title = "Diamonds") +
  annotate(geom='point', x=x.axis.labels, y = 0, ymin=-10, ymax=10) +
  annotate(geom='text', x=x.axis.labels, y = -200, label=x.axis.labels, vjust=1)
```

[image]